# Spring Kafka ConsumerConfig incorrectly lists StringDeserializer instead of KafkaAvroDeserializer for value.deserializer

Tags: spring-boot, avro, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

When starting Spring Boot `2.4.5` with `spring-kafa`, `value.deserializer` value is shown as `StringDeserializer` instead of `KafkaAvroDeserializer`:

```
2021-05-12 13:46:05.313  INFO 12632 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 

...  Elided for brevity ...

key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

**My configuration:**

```
@Bean
public Map<String, User> consumerConfigAvro() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "dnk23");
    props.put( AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:18081");
    props.put( KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true );
    props.put( KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY, TopicRecordNameStrategy.class.getName());

    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, User> consumerFactoryAvro() {
    KafkaAvroDeserializer kafkaAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
    kafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(consumerConfigAvro(), false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigAvro(),
            new StringDeserializer(),
            kafkaAvroDeserializer);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryAvro() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryAvro());
    return factory;
}
```

I'm running into the following exception, but after spending a lot of time, I think the root cause is `value.deserializer` is not set correctly.

```
    org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.example.sandbox.SandboxApplication.listen3(com.example.sandbox.avro.User)]
Bean [com.example.sandbox.SandboxApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9af3650b@5afcde28]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.sandbox.avro.User] for GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.sandbox.avro.User] for GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2114) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2102) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2001) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1928) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1814) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1531) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.sandbox.avro.User] for GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:341) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2069) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2051) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1988) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.sandbox.avro.User] for GenericMessage [payload=    $Henry Green Engine, headers={kafka_offset=18, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@259a8378, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, X-APP-EVENT=ApplicationCreatedEvent, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some-key, kafka_receivedTopic=topic3, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620841566436, kafka_groupId=myId3}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:145) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:926) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:330) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

**Listener**

```
@KafkaListener(id = "myId3", topics = "topic3")
public void listen3(@Payload User rec) {
    System.out.println(rec.getName());
}
```

**Producer**

```
                User user = User.newBuilder()
                        .setName("Henry Green Engine")
                        .setNumber(count)
                        .build();

                Message<User> message3 = MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(user)
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "topic3")
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "some-key")
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, 0)
                        .setHeader("X-APP-EVENT", "ApplicationCreatedEvent")
                        .build();

                kafkaTemplate3.send(message3);
```

**Avro schema**

```
{
  "namespace": "com.example.sandbox.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "number", "type": "int"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a non-standard container factory bean name (default is `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`), you have to specify the factory bean name on the `@KafkaListener`.

```java
public @interface KafkaListener {

...

    /**
     * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory}
     * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
     * <p>
     * If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any. If a SpEL
     * expression is provided ({@code #{...}}), the expression can either evaluate to a
     * container factory instance or a bean name.
     * @return the container factory bean name.
     */
    String containerFactory() default "";
```

So `..., containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactoryAvro", ...)`

Comment: I should get a +1 just because Gary Russell answered my question